# Is this valid variant of builder pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

Let's assume we have `User` and `UserBuilder` class in their own package, that we want to be immutable and at consistent state before initialization, defined as follows:

```
public class User {

private final String firstName, lastName;
private final int age;
private final String adress;
  protected User(UserBuilder buildUser) { //constructor acessible only in same packge
      this.firstName = buildUser.lastName;
      this.lastName = buildUser.lastName;
      this.age = buildUser.age;
      this.adress = buildUser.adress;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
  }
  ... // and other getters
}
```

And the builder class as follows:

```
public class UserBuilder {

    public final String firstName;
    public final String lastName;
    public int age;
    public String adress;

    public UserBuilder(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public UserBuilder setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder getUser() {
        return this;
    }

    public User build() {
        return new User(getUser());
    }
}
```

And finally we build the user in class that is in another package:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new UserBuilder("John","Doe")
                .setAge(22)
                .build();   
       // User user = new User(UserBuilder) //error protected constructor                
    }
```

Is this considered safe and good design? If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

**My suggestions:**

- Place the `Builder` inside the `User`, so it is more trivial what the
  `Builder` builds and User can access the private fields of the
  Builder, therefore no getter needed in the builder.
- Make `User` constructor `private`, because `protected` means derived classes can access the constructor, so immutability can broke.
- the `getUser()` method is unnecessary.

**Here is my example:**

```
public final class User {

    private final String firstName, lastName;
    private final int age;
    private final String address;
    private final List<User> friends;

    private User(Builder builder) {
        this.firstName = builder.lastName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        this.age = builder.age;
        this.address = builder.address;
        this.friends = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(builder.friends)); //immutable list
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public List<User> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    /**
     * other getters;
     */

    public static class Builder {
        private String firstName, lastName;
        private int age;
        private String address;
        private List<User> friends = new ArrayList<>();

        public Builder(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public Builder setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder addFriend(User friend) {
            this.friends.add(friend);
            return this;
        }

        public User build() {
            return new User(Builder.this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User johnSmith = new User.Builder("John", "Smith").setAge(33).setAddress("New York").build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Also classes within the same package can access `protected` members. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving inmutable object, so this is right. But you are creating a User object aware of the builder object, and I think this is not right because the User class does not have to know that there is a builder class, you are coupling the two classes, i mean, User depends directly on UserBuilder, without UserBuilder User can not compile and this is not a good design

I Think you would have a better design following the another answers to the questions, with those examples you will delete the classes coupling

Answer (score 0):

1. Place UserBuilder inside User
2. Create constructor of User taking first/last name, address, age
3. Make constructor of User private

Comment: I wanted to avoid nested builder, because I find it degrades code readability.  I know if you have nested builder you can have private constructor.

Comment: Then choose default user constructor visibility, not protected

Comment: But then you can pass UserBuilder inside User constructor in inconsistent state by calling the constructor of User and using UserBuilder instance that may or may not be fully initialized, which makes the whole exercise of having Builder pointless.

Comment: Maybe not worry then about builder readability? It is a classical pattern

Answer (score 0):

protected is not accessible ONLY in the same package, but in sub-classes as well.
Include the Builder class as nested class in User.
This approach is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).